# JsViews - Alternating Templates

Tags: jsrender, jsviews

Does anyone know how would you apply an alternating template using JsViews?

For example is there a way to generate markup like this?

```
<table>
 <thead></thead>
 <tbody>
   <tr class="odd"></tr>
   <tr class="even"></tr>
 </tbody>    
</table>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within a template, the index is available using `#index`

There is an `{{if}}` construct that can be used to alternate between two choices.

The untested code would be something like:

```
{{if #index % 2 }}
    code for odd case
{{else}}
    code for even case
{{/if}}
```

Do a view source of [this](http://borismoore.github.io/jsrender/demos/step-by-step/01_inserting-data.html) to see a simple use of #index.

Do a view source of [this](http://borismoore.github.io/jsrender/demos/step-by-step/04_if-else-tag.html) to see a simple use of if, then, else.